# Calculating the difference between two dates in different timezones in hours and minutes

Tags: algorithms, programming-languages

I need to calculate the difference between two dates in hours and in minutes which is what the code below does. 
The only issue I have is that the dates and the location (timezone) has to be input by the user. How do I achieve that? Can be a different language from PHP as I only need a flowchart and the pseudocode.

?php

$departure = new DateTime('8pm March 27, 2016 America/New_York');

$arrival = new DateTime('7:20am March 28, 2016 Europe/London');

$flighttime = $departure->diff($arrival);

echo "$flighttime-> h hours $flight_time->i minutes";

Output:
7 hours 20 minutes

Comment: What's the problem exactly? That the `'8pm March 27, 2016 America/New_York'` string comes from user input? Are you asking how to validate it?

Comment: $departure = new DateTime('8pm March 27, 2016 America/New_York');      Inside of the bracket, I need that to be the user input, so the user inputs that information.

Comment: So you're asking how to take a string from a some textarea in some html and run your code on it?

Comment: Yes, I want the user to input the date and the location from which the timezone is taken and then run the code on it to calculate the difference between the two inputted dates.

Comment: You're asking for an algorithm but this is something for which you should use your programming environment's built-in date and time handling routines, rather than trying to roll your own code. This is the sort of thing where reinventing the wheel just causes mistakes from obscure cases.

Comment: Coding questions, programming questions, and questions specific to a particular language are off-topic here.  I suggest that you remove all source code (e.g., PHP code) and replace it with pseudocode, concepts, and ideas.  Also, proof-read your post.  It didn't turn out like I suspect you intended for it to.

Answer (score 1):

TimeA -> ConvertToTimeZoneUtc -> NormalizeToGreenwichUtcTime -> ConvertToTicks
Same for timeB
( ticksA - tickB) => timepsan. GetHours | GetMins

Is that ok?

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! It seems like a good idea converting to one format and make calculations there but a textual description would be nice and please make sure that question is on-topic and not a duplicate before providing an answer.